# Help with resistor rating

Tags: resistors, ratings

I'm having a problem with finding out the value of resistor that has 5 band color code but matches 4 band color code. I'm presuming its 0.47 5%, but I could be wrong.

Resistor is blown and there is no similar resistor anywhere on board to match measure ratings.

Device is Samsung HT-F4200, an DVD player and smart box.

I appreciate any help offered. I really don't wanna see this device going in junk for what it seems one faulty resistor.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 0.47\$\Omega\$. The black band is just to tell you which end is the right-hand one. Probably a 5% metal oxide film (flameproof) type that also acts as a fuse.

Chances are very good that something else has failed to cause this catastrophic failure- such as a MOSFET or high voltage transistor, so replacing that resistor will more than likely result in a repetition of the failure (correct type) or possibly more dramatic results (wrong type of resistor).

Comment: Thanks for help. Player was probably damaged in storm but I'm not sure because I wasn't home at the time (people told me there was a big storm that week). EDIT: I have one of those resistors laying around but its 5w with aluminium cooler. Will it fit my aplication?

Comment: @Ripaz if the resistor is intended to act as a fuse, putting in a "bulky" one of 5W will not work, since the resistor will not burn at the expected current, but a much higher one.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. You might saved me from buying new device.